# Freeipa krb credentials not destroyed, after logout from system via DM

Tags: sssd, freeipa

When login to system (in IPA domain) via lightdm, kerberos credentials are automatically created.
After logout, they are not destroyed.

Steps for reproduse:

1. Login to system via GUI as **user**.
2. Logout.
3. Login as root, and **su - user**
4. **klist** shows credentials for **user** and you have ability to login other machines in domain as that **user**

For workaround in GDM I add:
**sudo -u ${USERNAME} kdestroy**
before **exit 0** to /etc/gdm/PostSession/Default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known (minor) issue with [SSSD](https://pagure.io/SSSD/sssd/) that serves as FreeIPA domain client. You can check for additional information in in:

- [related sssd-users thread](https://lists.fedorahosted.org/archives/list/sssd-users@lists.fedorahosted.org/thread/WDMKFKIBJ3DG2B6QYW6NMT6A7TXZKCZV/)
- [SSSD ticket for the issue](https://pagure.io/SSSD/sssd/issue/2992)